# Vector Surface Integral over an Entire Sphere

Tags: surfaces, vector-fields, surface-integrals

This is a short, conceptual question related to the post: [Surface integral of position vector over a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051762/surface-integral-of-position-vector-over-a-sphere)

We have a vector field integrated over the the entire surface of a sphere of radius $a$, and this field has constant magnitude $a$ at all points on the sphere. The answer is fairly trivially $4\pi a^3$, but I don't understand why each vector pointing out of the sphere is exactly cancelled by a vector on the antipode of the sphere, meaning everything cancels out and leaves us 0. It might be something fundamentally wrong with my interpretation of a vector surface integral. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what you want to calculate. Can you give an example? If your vector field is $\vec F$ and the normal to the surface is $\hat n$, are you calculating $\int\vec F ds$ or $\int\vec F\cdot\hat n ds$?

Comment: @Andrei The second one - which is always the case when evaluating surface integrals of vector fields (I had assumed). Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: First, a quick example of both cases, taken from physics. Given an electric field $\vec E$, calculating the flux through a sphere is your second type of integral. Now given the same electric field, and assuming that it's an external one, calculating the force on a uniformly charged spherical shell is the first type of integral.

Comment: Secondly, you make some assumptions about the direction of the vector field, which you did not describe in the problem. Say my field is $\vec F=a\hat x$. It has constant magnitude over the sphere, but $\int\vec F\cdot\hat n ds=0$. I think this is where you get confused. If $\vec F=a\hat r$, then the field cancels in opposite points, but $\vec F\cdot\hat n$ does not (it is constant for the case I considered)

Comment: @Andrei in the post I linked above, $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{\hat{r}}$ and so "the field cancels in opposite points" is what should be occurring here, no? Instead we see a nonzero answer for this flux out of the sphere.